# How do I add percentage signs to an axis in barplot in R?

Tags: r, bar-chart, axis-labels

I currently have the following code

```
    testdata <- data.frame(one=c(.25),two=c(.25),three=c(.5))

b <- barplot(t(testdata*100), col=c("darkred","darkblue","darkgoldenrod"), cex.axis=0.7,horiz=TRUE,border=NA)
text(b, x = c(.125,.375,.75)*100, c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3"), cex=.7, col="white")
text(b, x = c(0,20,40,60,80,100), y=0, labels = rep("%",6), cex=.7)
```

but I want instead of having to multiply by 100, have it interpret as a percentage and add "%" after each increment in the axis label (or at least the latter).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is easier to suppress the axis when plotting with `barplot()` (using `axes = FALSE`) and then add the axis by hand where you can control the positioning of the ticks and the labels that go with them. The code below is one way to do this

```
b <- barplot(t(testdata), col = c("darkred","darkblue","darkgoldenrod"), 
             horiz = TRUE, border = NA, axes = FALSE)
labs <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.25)
text(b, x = c(0.125, 0.375, 0.75), labels = c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3"),
     cex = 0.7, col = "white")
axis(side = 1, at = labs, labels = paste0(labs * 100, "%"), cex.axis = 0.7)
```

which produces

[image]

Is that what you were looking to get?